# How to smooth SVG line

Tags: svg

Exmaple is by [link](https://jsfiddle.net/)

[image]

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <line x1="0" y1="80" x2="100" y2="20" stroke="black" />
    </svg>
```

As you can notice the end of line has cut corner, not filled to the end of border. How to smooth this?

Comment: It's cut, because x2 is 100, which is the width of the viewbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clarify what you mean by "filled to end of border".

If you mean that you want the line to go all the way to the SVG border without seeing the end of it, then there are two solutions.

1. Draw your line a little longer. So it goes all the way off the SVG.  Right now it stops right at the border, and because of the angle, part of the end is visible.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <line x1="-2" y1="80" x2="102" y2="20" stroke="black" />
</svg>
```

2. Alternatively, you could give the line square end caps. That will extend the line a little, so it will go just far enough.  However this will only work if your line isn't too steep.  If it gets steeper than 45 degrees, the end of the line will start to become visible again.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <line x1="0" y1="80" x2="100" y2="20" stroke="black" stroke-linecap="square" />
</svg>
```

Comment: I use canvas 2d

Answer (score 1):

The corner is truncated because it goes beyond your canvas. Just make your canvas a little bigger or your line a little smaller and it will work

Here's an exemple where i moved the line by 1 unit to the right and made the canvas sligtly bigger. You can see that the corners are as they sould be

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 101 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <line x1="1" y1="80" x2="100" y2="20" stroke="black" />
    </svg>
```

Comment: Does not work, set border to svg and you can see white space between border and end of line

Comment: If to chnage `x2="101"` it works, but it is not good idea

Comment: I moved x1 to 1 and made the canvas 101 unit wide. Your corners are cut because they are drawn past the viewbox. You cannot draw beyond your viewbox. The only way to achieve what you want is to either make the viewbox bigger so it can fit the whole line or make the line smaller so it fits in the viewbox. There is no way to draw pas the viewbox

Comment: I did not get what you did, set `svg {
  border:1px solid red;
}` and check

Comment: Do  I need https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-linecap?